# Picture from cloud storage showing in debug mode but not in release apk-flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, cloud-storage

I am showing image from firebase cloud storage to the flutter app through stream builder. I am showing image in alert dialog when the button presses. The picture is showing fine in debug mode but not showing in release mode. I have tried getting apk with --no-shrink but the error is still same. my functionality is when the user selects month and year from the drop down and press button, a picture shows in alert dialog of that month which is saved in cloud storage. [Picture in release apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtDfv.jpg)[Picture in debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8Efc.jpg)

```
**Future showimage() async {
return showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
        child: AlertDialog(
            content: Expanded(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: storage.downloadedUrl('${dropdownmonth}${dropdowndate}', '${dropdownmonth}${dropdowndate}Record'),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snap) {
              if (snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                  snap.hasData) {
                return Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 1,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                        return Container(
                            width: 400,
                            height: 450,
                            child: Image.network(
                              snap.data!,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ));
                      }),
                );
                //Container(width: 300,height: 450,
                // child: Image.network(snap.data!,
                // fit: BoxFit.cover,),
              }
              if (snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
              if(snap.data==null){
                return Center(child: Text("No Report Found"));
              }
              return Container();
            },
          ),
        )),
      );
    });
```

}**

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by removing some widgets like expanded, flex. I ran the update in release mood by flutter run --release

Answer (score 0):

Add the line in blow into your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Something like this:

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.stagered_grid_view">

// ----------------------------------------
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
// ----------------------------------------
    
   <application
        android:label="stagered_grid_view"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```